# the connection with dbGetQuery doesnt work properly

Tags: mysql, sql, r

I am trying to know whats the error , i am very new in R but i have the following error (near "": syntax error")

can you support please??

the code

```
shinyServer(function (input, output, session) {

output$ppcpOut <- reactive({
  input$user1
})  


output$propertyOut <- reactive({
  input$user2
})
  

ppcpquery <- reactive({
  input$user1
})  

query <- reactive({
  paste('SELECT solubility FROM mytable WHERE PPCP = "%s"', ppcpquery())
})


output$valueout <- reactive({
  
  dbGetQuery(db,query())
  
})

#propertyquery <- eventReactive ({input$user2})  

session$onSessionEnded (function()
  {
  dbDisconnect(db)
})

})
```

Thanks

Comment: Pretty sure you can't do that with `paste`. That function concatenates, it doesn't replace.

Comment: do you a recommendation , would be very nice of you actually.

Comment: try this? `paste0("SELECT solubility FROM mytable WHERE PPCP = '", ppcpquery(), "'")`

Comment: I usually use `gsub` for things like this... `gsub("<ppc>", ppcquery(), "select solubility from mytable where ppcp = '<ppc>'")`

Comment: Don't use `sprintf` or `paste`, it's much better to use parameter-binding, something like `dbGetQuery(con, "select ... where PPCP = ?", params = list(ppcpquery()))`. (I think mysql uses `?` ...)

Comment: While there are security concerns about malicious [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (e.g., XKCD's [*Exploits of a Mom*](https://xkcd.com/327/) aka "Little Bobby Tables"), it is also a concern for malformed strings or Unicode-vs-ANSI mistakes, even if it's a single data analyst running the query. Both `DBI` (with `odbc`) and `RODBC` support parameterized queries, either natively or via add-ons.

Comment: Thanks again ,  it tells me that there is no table,.. this will drive me crazy ..sorry @cory

Comment: "no table" when you know there should be one there is often one of: (a) you and your DBA are on a different wavelength; (b) the table was created in a local (single-user) namespace or as a temporary table; or (c) you may need to prepend with the *schema* (namespace) of the table, e.g., `dbo.mytable`).